# Foxit Reader is not responding on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, foxitreader

I downloade Foxit Reader from [here](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads) and then extracted and installed it.

However, after using it for a while, Foxit Reader freezes with a popup:

> Foxit Reader is not responding, please wait or force quit

I don't know why this happens. Do you know any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 15):

Start Foxit without opening any pdf file. Go to Edit --> Preferences. Go to Updater and uncheck. Go also to General and Disable ConnectedPDF features. I haven't tested if only one step would be sufficient.

Comment: This seems to work for Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon which is based on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this always happens to me with Foxit Reader. My workaround is to *Force Quit* it until it starts responding. **Usually it takes at least 2 to 3 tries.**

You can see what's happening on your system with a command like:

```
grep -i -B 10 -A 10  'foxit' /var/log/syslog
```

But I love the app and it's worth it to me to go through this inconvenience until this gets fixed. I just filed a support request with https://www.foxitsoftware.com/ and included some of the log output. It may help if you also report the specifics of your problem to them.

Comment: `sudo killall FoxitReader` is the quickest way.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it running the installer as administrator. I hope that could be useful for you.

Comment: There is no administrator in Ubuntu that is a windows term. In Ubuntu it would be use sudo

Answer (score 2):

FoxIt seems to be no longer maintained. You can check out the official statement [in the foxit forum](https://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/183039-foxit-reader-freeze-on-ubuntu-20-04).

**TL;DR;** The existing version of FoxIt Reader requires Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 - 16.10. So it doesn't support Ubuntu 20.04 (and also not 18.04, and so on).

Comment: Can this be solved by creating an Ubuntu SNAP with a 16.10 base image?